# Does "in-between" multiplication preserve equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

In a magma $(S;*)$, multiplication on the left and the right preserves equality. That is, if $a=b$, then $c*a=c*b$ and $a*c=b*c$. But what about "in-between" multiplication? That is, if $a*c=b*c$, does it follow that $(a*d)*c=(b*d)*c$? Or, as I think is more likely, is there a magma where that property does not hold?

Comment: The property holds if the magma is commutative and associative.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Commutativity is not required, only associativity.

Comment: @Angel Really? I think the accepted answer gives a counterexample to your claim, since composition of functions is associative.

Comment: @AlexKruckman My bad. I forgot to specify that cancellability is required. $c$ must be right-cancellable. But commutativity is still not required. And in the accepted answer, $c$ is not cancellable. None of the functions, except $d,$ is right-cancellable in that example.

Comment: @Angel If $c$ is right-cancellable, then $a*c = b*c$ implies $a = b$, from which it follows immediately that $(a*d)*c = (b*d)*c$. So if $c$ is right-cancellable, then we don't even need associativity!

Comment: If $c$ is right-cancellable, then $a\star{c}=b\star{c}$ implies $a=b,$ and $a=b$ implies $a\star(d\star{c})=b\star(d\star{c}).$ Finally, the above, together with associativity implies $(a\star{d})\star{c}=(b\star{d})\star{c}.$ No commutativity required. $c$ being right-cancellable is a much weaker condition than the necessary commutation relations.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You are right. I overlooked that.

Comment: @AlexKruckman So then, it seems to me that a condition as weak as right-cancellability is sufficient. Associativity and commutativity are stronger conditions.

Comment: @Angel I don't share the intuition that right-cancellability is a weaker condition than commutativity or associativity. In the context of general magmas, all three conditions seem like very strong assumptions to me! But in any case, I think we agree that the desired result holds if either (1) $*$ is commutative and associative, or (2) $*$ has right-cancellability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135996/discussion-between-angel-and-alex-kruckman).

Comment: @Angel I've responded to your last chat message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b, c: \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be linear maps. Suppose that $c(x, y) = (x, 0)$.  Suppose that $a(x, y) = (0, y), b(x, y) = (0, -y)$.  Then $a\circ c = b\circ c = 0$.  Let $d(x, y) = (y, x)$.  Then $(a\circ d \circ c)(x,y) = (0, x)$ and $(b \circ d \circ c)(x, y) = (0, -x)$.